# What is the significance of union in this code, what is the disadvantage if structure?

Tags: c, structure, unions

```
struct queue_entry_s {

    odp_buffer_hdr_t *head;
    odp_buffer_hdr_t *tail;
    int               status;

    enq_func_t       enqueue ODP_ALIGNED_CACHE;
    deq_func_t       dequeue;
    enq_multi_func_t enqueue_multi;
    deq_multi_func_t dequeue_multi;

    odp_queue_t       handle;
    odp_buffer_t      sched_buf;
    odp_queue_type_t  type;
    odp_queue_param_t param;
    odp_pktio_t       pktin;
    odp_pktio_t       pktout;
    char              name[ODP_QUEUE_NAME_LEN];
};

typedef union queue_entry_u {
    struct queue_entry_s s;
    uint8_t pad[ODP_CACHE_LINE_SIZE_ROUNDUP(sizeof(struct queue_entry_s))];
} queue_entry_t;

typedef struct queue_table_t {
    queue_entry_t  queue[ODP_CONFIG_QUEUES];                                                                                           
} queue_table_t;

static queue_table_t *queue_tbl;

#define ODP_CACHE_LINE_SIZE 64

#define ODP_ALIGN_ROUNDUP(x, align)\                                                                                                   
    ((align) * (((x) + align - 1) / (align)))

#define ODP_CACHE_LINE_SIZE_ROUNDUP(x)\
    ODP_ALIGN_ROUNDUP(x, ODP_CACHE_LINE_SIZE)
```

In the above code, **typedef union queue_entry_u**, What is the significance of the union. If we take structure(**typedef struct queue_entry_u**), Is there any disadvantage?

Comment: You should take a look at the `ODP_CACHE_LINE_SIZE_ROUNDUP` macro, and/or edit the macro into the question. Basically, the `union` adds padding bytes to the struct, so that the memory used is a multiple of some desirable value.

Comment: @user3386109, Added definition of macro, as you have asked for.

Comment: There should be option to select 2 accepted answer. Both answers clarify the reason.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`unions` have several usages:

- `union` saves some memory. It makes it so that `s` and `pad` sit in the same place in memory. It is useful if you know that only one of them is needed then you can use a `union`.
- It is also useful to be able to iterate over the fields in your struct. By saving the fields in a union you have both an array and a struct so if you iterate over `pad` you are in essence iterating over the bytes of `s`.
- `unions` are also useful in general for casting. The syntax is a little prettier to serialize your entry into a byte array by just using the `union`.
- In this case it looks like the use of a `union` is to pad the size of `s` to fit in a cache line. This way if the size of a `queue_entry_s` is an exact multiple of the length of a cache line `s` then `pad` will sit in exactly the same memory and not waste space. Otherwise `pad` will take more memory than `s` and the size of the `union` will always be an exact multiple of the length of a cache line.

This being said it is usually only a good idea to use `unions` if you are writing embedded code for devices very low on memory or with very stringent performance requirements. They are very dangerous and very easy to misuse by accidentally writing over memory that was meant to represent the other type in the `union`.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with the definition of a union from K&R 2nd edition:

> A union is a variable that may hold (at different times) objects of
>   different types [...]. Unions provide a way to manipulate different
>   kinds of data in a single area of storage.

The union in the question contains two objects: a structure of type `struct queue_entry_s` and a array of `uint8_t`. It's important to note that those two objects overlap in memory. Specifically, the address where the structure starts is the same as the address where the array starts. If you write to the structure, the contents of the array will be changed, and if you write to the array, then the contents of the structure will be changed.

Then note that the `ODP_CACHE_LINE_SIZE_ROUNDUP` macro takes a size and computes the smallest multiple of 64 that is greater than or equal to that size.

The size of the union is determined by the size of the largest member. So for example, if the `sizeof(struct queue_entry_s)` is 80, then the sizeof of the `pad` array will be 128, and the sizeof the union will be 128.

Which brings us finally to the answer. The purpose of the union is to increase the memory used by the structure, so that the structure always uses a multiple of 64 bytes of memory.

If you were to change `typedef union queue_entry_u` to `typedef struct queue_entry_u`, then the memory layout would be changed. Instead of a having `s` and `pad` overlapping in memory, the `pad` array would follow the `s` structure in memory. So if `s` occupies 80 bytes and `pad` occupies 128 bytes, then the `typedef struct queue_entry_u` would define an object that occupies 208 bytes of memory. That would be a waste of memory, and wouldn't comply with the multiple-of-64 requirement.